# If 2 checkbox's are ticked perform jquery function

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Hi I have the following code but cannot get it working. I want to show the link once both checkbox's have been checked.

HTML:

```
<div><input id="dp-terms" name="terms" type="checkbox" value="1" /> I have read and agree       to your terms and conditions</div>
<div><input id="dp-artwork" name="artwork" type="checkbox" value="1" /> I have read and undertand your artwork guide</div>
<div id="show-continue" style="display:none;"><a href="#">Next ></a></div>
```

jQuery;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dp-terms, #dp-artwork").change(function() {       
        if ($("input#dp-terms").checked && ("input#dp-artwork").checked) {
            $("#show-continue").show();
        } else {
            $("#show-continue").hide();
        };
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dannyj6/EJZuC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checked` is a property on DOM node, not the jQuery object, hence you have to write:

```
$("input#dp-terms")[0].checked
```

Also you forgot the dollar sign when you tried to check the second checkbox. Here is the working code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dp-terms, #dp-artwork").change(function() {       
        if ($("input#dp-terms")[0].checked && $("input#dp-artwork")[0].checked) {
            $("#show-continue").show();
        } else {
            $("#show-continue").hide();
        };
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EJZuC/2/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#dp-terms, #dp-artwork").change(function () {
        $("#show-continue").css('display', ($("#dp-terms").is(':checked') && $("#dp-artwork").is(':checked')) ? '' : 'none');
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EJZuC/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dp-terms, #dp-artwork").click(function() {      
        alert('in');
        if ($("input#dp-terms").is(":checked") && $("input#dp-artwork").is(":checked") ) {
            $("#show-continue").show();
        } else {
            $("#show-continue").hide();
        };
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EJZuC/3/